# Ngx-editor "Choose Imagen"

Tags: ngx-editor

I have installed ngx-editor, but when trying to upload an image it does not leave me and gives an error, both with "jpg" and with "png".

They are files from my local computer, and they are small in size.

From what I see in the official example, it does not stop going up either, it gives me the same error:

https://ngx-editor.stackblitz.io/

ERROR:

```
Imagen endpoint isn't provided or invalid
```

Comment: Have you figured out how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this documentation page](https://sibiraj-s.github.io/ngx-editor/additional-documentation/image-uploader.html).

You need to implement your own endpoint API, which should receive the file via HTTP POST, store it somewhere then return a JSON containing the url of the file saved to your server.